# How to hide posts of particular year from archive lising

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress is showing archive in month and year wise listing
From admin, there is an option to show count for posts.
But If the user wants only show / Hide listing of a particular year, This setting is not given.
How will this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference of how to hide or only pass the archive years needed.

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'year'  => 2012,
            'month' => 12,
        ),
        array(
            'year'  => 2012,
            'month' => 11,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can also pass it to `pre_get_posts` hook as well,

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'date_query'); 
    function date_query($query){
        if(is_archive()){
           $query->set('date_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'year'  => 2012,
                'month' => 12,
            ),
            array(
                'year'  => 2012,
                'month' => 11,
            ),
        ));
        }  
     return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks , 
After searching i have use below filter. 
It will change query and hide entries of current and previous year .

```
function filter_hide_previous_2year_post( $text, $r ) 
{
$year=date("Y",strtotime("-1 year"));
return "WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'  and  
YEAR(post_date)>= '".$year."' ";
}


add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'filter_hide_previous_2year_post', 10, 2 );
```